# Printing HttpResponseMessage in string format

Tags: c#, httpclient

Is there any good way or in build function to print a `HttpResponseMessage` in string format, like

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
ETag: "lGaP-E0memYDumK16YuUDM_6Gf0/V43j6azD55CPRGb9b6uytDYl61Y"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 22 Jan 2013 18:56:00 GMT
Expires: Tue, 22 Jan 2013 18:56:00 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 247

{
 "kind": "storage#objectAccessControl",
 "id": "example-bucket/obj1/allUsers",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1beta2/b/example-bucket/o/obj1    /acl/allUsers",
 "bucket": "example-bucket",
 "object": "obj1",
 "entity": "allUsers",
 "role": "READER"
}
```

One thing I can do is manually read fields from `HttpResponseMessage` and print in this fashion, but that seems very error prone to me and I think there should be some standard way in `C# for doing this.

Comment: `HttpResponseMessage.ToString()` nearly does what you want, it just doesn't include the content. You could read the content stream and append that, but you'll have to do some testing as to whether you can then re-read the content stream further down the line (to actually process it).